# Search between two date fields in wrong format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table where the date column (sessionend) values look like this:

```
Sep 10, 2013 2:33 AM
```

Here are my user input dates:

```
$convertedStart = '2013-08-01 00:00:01';
$convertedEnd = '2013-10-15 23:59:59';
```

Here is my query

```
"SELECT * FROM `tictoc` WHERE sessionend BETWEEN '".$convertedStart."' AND '".$convertedEnd."'"
```

How do i convert the time coming from the DB so i can search using this format:

```
yyy-mm-dd 00:00:00
```

Thanks

Comment: the real solution is to fix your table so you're storing NATIVE date/time values instead of random-ish text strings. Then your problem goes away and things just start working.

Comment: That is the correct solution. but the program that outputs the date as  Sep 10, 2013 2:33 AM, and is imported via a CSV. I currently have 1000's of dates already stored in that format.

Comment: the fix the dates when you're reading from the csv file. better to convert the dates to native ONCE, rather than having to convert them on-the-fly everytime you want to run your query.

Comment: I have to agree with Marc. It would also be pretty quick to update the current dates already stored in the database.

Comment: True, I will just go through an make the changes in my php to convert from the csv file. Then go in and convert the current ones to native. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Best solution would be to convert your datetime format to native one.**

Add new field `new_field` to table as `DATETIME` type. Then run query:

```
UPDATE `tictoc`
SET `new_field` = STR_TO_DATE(`sessionend`, '%b %e, %Y %l:%i %p');
```

then delete your old field `sessionend`, and rename field `new_field` into `sessionend`.

---

You can still run query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tictoc` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`sessionend`, '%b %e, %Y %l:%i %p') BETWEEN '$convertedStart' AND '$convertedEnd'
```

but this will ignore any indexes on field `sessionend`, and loop over all records in table.

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime() and date():

```
$originalDate = "Sep 10, 2013 2:33 AM";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Comment: I did, but when i convert the user input to this format 'Sep 10, 2013 2:33 AM' it doesnt seem to run the query correctly. I get all results returned. So im guessing it's not possible to select values between this format: Sep 10, 2013 2:33 AM

Comment: Using the above I get an output of 2013-09-10 02:33:00 (which is in line with the other dates you are getting). In your query try sessionend >= date1 AND sessionend <= date2?

Comment: Not going to work. Using this method will be causing the OP to compare STRINGS in the database, and `Dec 12` is LESS than `Sep 12`, because `D` comes before `S` in the alphabet

Comment: Thanks but that didnt work. I think i may just convert the date after the query add an IF statement to only show the row if it is is between the two dates.

Answer (score 0):

you can take times away  from each other using  the  strtotime(): this converts to a  unix timestamp

but if you want to make it into a date use the date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $variable)